# Using if statements in for loops

Tags: javascript, arrays, if-statement, for-loop

Currently I am using an if statement inside of a for loop counting an array

```
for(count = 0; count < order.length; count++)
{
    if(order[count] == "")
    {
        alert("You must select an item");
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        $.mobile.changePage();
        $("#idTag").after("<p>"+order[count]+"<p/>");
    }
}
```

My issue is that if order[0] has information in it and if any other array index has no information the alert will still run when I don't want it to. Is there anyway to make sure that once the array is checked it just runs through the else statement without going back to the if statement.

Any help would be appreciated

John

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maintain a `flag`

```
var flag  = 0;

for(count = 0; count < order.length; count++)
{
    if(order[count] == "" && flag == 0)
    {
        alert("You must select an item");
        break;
    }
    else
    {
        flag = 1;
        $.mobile.changePage();
    }
}
if(flag == 1)
    return false;
```

Comment: I thought this would work for sure but it seems like it doesn't it still shoots out the alert on the second run

Comment: I think you can fix that by setting `flag = 1;` in the `else` block.

Comment: @Exo That fixed it, thanks. Editing answer to reflect working result

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want to break out of the loop as soon as you have an order whose value is not `""`. This can be accomplished by adding a `break` statement.

```
for(count = 0; count < order.length; count++)
{
    if(order[count] == "")
    {
        alert("You must select an item");
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        $.mobile.changePage();
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: The issue with this (I'll update the question now) is that I still need the for loop to run because I use the count in the else statement as well

Answer (score 1):

First, wonder if you need to make `count` variable local (as in local to whichever function the contains the for loop). Second, there shouldn't be any problem in breaking the loop in else condition after the desired jQuery code is run. Try the following code,

```
for(var count = 0; count < order.length; count++)
{
    if(order[count] == "")
    {
        alert("You must select an item");
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        $.mobile.changePage();
        $("#idTag").after("<p>"+order[count]+"<p/>");
        break;
    }
}
```